# Showing file name using \inputminted

Tags: minted

I would like to make \inputminted to show the file name before the contents.

I could not find an option for this at

http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/minted/minted.pdf

Is there an option for this?

Comment: Only partially. The answer you posted does not use the inputminted command and it gets the program text from the LaTeX file, not a file on the disk.

Comment: `\newcommand\zzz[1]{file: #1\par\inputminted{#1}}`  then `\zzz{myfile.py}` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks especially for the \par TeX idiom.